# BottomSheetDialogFragment is not open, small white bar only show

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have created `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and access into my fragment but it not open fully, it shows only small bar in bottom like below

[image]

I am using default `BottomSheetDialogFragment` file without changing anything.

xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_spacing_half"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_item_spacing_half"
    tools:context=".ui.SettingFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_setting_list_dialog_item" />
```

Show call function

```kotlin
val addBottomDialogFragment: SettingFragment = SettingFragment.newInstance(10)

addBottomDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "tag")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height of BottomSheet depend on child content height So first you should add some child view or content under bottom sheet view. If you using RecyclerView then set adapter with data.

Answer (score 1):

Because your BottomSheet don't have content, You have to add content to it